# Order of execution in Airflow

Tags: python, airflow

I'm reviewing the example code [here](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/example_python_operator.py)

There are two "operation" function:

```
def my_sleeping_function(random_base):
    """This is a function that will run within the DAG execution"""
    time.sleep(random_base)
```

and:

```
def print_context(ds, **kwargs):
    pprint(kwargs)
    print(ds)
    return 'Whatever you return gets printed in the logs'
```

For each run of `my_sleeping_function` we run `print_context`?

What I don't understand is the order.
This is the graph and the Tree.. the execution order isn't the same:

[image]
[image]

What happens first? What happens after? Why?

I assume that according to this:

```
for i in range(5):
    task = PythonOperator(
        task_id='sleep_for_' + str(i),
        python_callable=my_sleeping_function,
        op_kwargs={'random_base': float(i) / 10},
        dag=dag)

    task.set_upstream(run_this)
```

run_this executes and then task executes but the loop confuses me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your confusion is based around you expecting the graph view and tree view to be two separate visualizing of the same thing. However they are used to visualize different things.

The graph view shows the order the tasks will run in your workflow.  In your case `print_the_context` will run, and once complete `sleep_for_0`, `sleep_for_1`, `sleep_for_2`, `sleep_for_3`, `sleep_for_4` will run be run in parallel (or at least as parallel as your airflow config will allow)

The tree view represents a depth first visualization of the DAG (and the status of each task over time in the squares to the right).  That is to say the the first level of nodes in the tree are final tasks in the dag (leaf nodes), where the dag will be considered successfully completed. It branches out for each dependent task that must be run for it to run.

To put it another way, the execution order is the same in both views, it is just being visualized from different directions.

Answer (score 2):

The loop here is just showing you how to dynamically build a DAG. The order in which things get executed depends on what you set as the "upstream" or "downstream" tasks.

The example that you linked to could also be done like the following example. However what if you want to add another 10 tasks? You'd have to do quite a lot of copy/paste coding to achieve the same thing, better to just put it in a loop as in the linked example:

```
def my_sleeping_function(random_base):
    """This is a function that will run within the DAG execution"""
    time.sleep(random_base)


def print_context(ds, **kwargs):
    pprint(kwargs)
    print(ds)
    return 'Whatever you return gets printed in the logs'


run_this = PythonOperator(
    task_id='print_the_context',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=print_context,
    dag=dag)

task_0 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='sleep_for_' + 0,
    python_callable=my_sleeping_function,
    op_kwargs={'random_base': float(0) / 10},
    dag=dag)

task_1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='sleep_for_' + 1,
    python_callable=my_sleeping_function,
    op_kwargs={'random_base': float(1) / 10},
    dag=dag)

task_2 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='sleep_for_' + 2,
    python_callable=my_sleeping_function,
    op_kwargs={'random_base': float(2) / 10},
    dag=dag)


task_3 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='sleep_for_' + 3,
    python_callable=my_sleeping_function,
    op_kwargs={'random_base': float(3) / 10},
    dag=dag)

task_4 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='sleep_for_' + 4,
    python_callable=my_sleeping_function,
    op_kwargs={'random_base': float(4) / 10},
    dag=dag)


task_0.set_upstream(run_this)
task_1.set_upstream(run_this)
task_2.set_upstream(run_this)
task_3.set_upstream(run_this)
task_4.set_upstream(run_this)
```

Comment: `+1`  

I was looking for something unrelated to the question asked here but your solution was useful for me out of coincidence :)

Answer (score 2):

@cwurtz is right!

To set order of the tasks you can use `priority_weight` task's parameter

> The pool parameter can be used in conjunction with priority_weight to define priorities in the queue, and which tasks get executed first as slots open up in the pool. ([Read more](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html))